# How do I store temp data from an Azure Function?

Tags: c#, sdk, azure-functions, zoho

I've written an Azure function to send data into the Zoho CRM SDK.  The SDK needs a file path to write some meta data while its in use (called "resourcePath").  While developing on my local I was using My Documents and it works fine.  I need to find a location I can use in the Azure environment.
Based on articles I've read, I've tried `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` and `context.FunctionAppDirectory'.`  Both of which throw a permissions error. The error is from the SDK `{{ "code": "OAUTH_SCOPE_MISMATCH", "status": "error", "message": "invalid oauth scope to access this URL" }}` 
I'm told that this is a permissions error on the file location.  What location I should be using for an Azure Function?

**Reply to @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT **

I made the path change and now I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in `CreateRecords()`.  The RecordOperations, moduleApiName and bodyWrapper are all valid.  Nothing is null.

`at Com.Zoho.Crm.API.Util.Utility.GetFieldsInfo(String moduleAPIName) at Com.Zoho.Crm.API.Util.Utility.GetFields(String moduleAPIName) at Com.Zoho.Crm.API.Record.RecordOperations.CreateRecords(String moduleAPIName, BodyWrapper request) at Zoho_CRM_Feed.feed_app.Lead.CreateNewLead(List1 leads) in C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\source\repos\Zoho_CRM_Feed\Zoho_CRM_Feed\feed_app\Lead.cs:line 75`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()`, this will create a `%userprofile%\Local\Temp\tmpE128.tmp` file
OR

```
 System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(),  
    System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName())
```

If you are getting error INVALID_TOKEN please [generate](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/access-refresh.html) a new access token and check if you are still getting the same error.